# Efficient way to count associated objects in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a way to show a count of how many `images` there are for a `category` but obtained through a `has_many` association. I have been reading a little on `counter_cache` but as yet no joy on an implementation

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories
  has_many :images, through: :image_categories
end

class ImageCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Holds image_id and category_id to allow multiple categories to be saved per image, as opposed to storing an array of objects in one DB column
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :category
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Categories
  has_many :image_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :image_categories
end
```

Controller

```
@categories  = Category.all
```

View

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to '#', data: { :filter => '.' + c.name.delete(' ') } do %>
      <%= c.name %> (<%= #count here %>)
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for an efficient way, i would suggest using `counter_cache`

Here is how your models should look like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories
  has_many :images, through: :image_categories
end

class ImageCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Holds image_id and category_id to allow multiple categories to be saved per image, as opposed to storing an array of objects in one DB column
  belongs_to :image, counter_cache: :category_count
  belongs_to :category, counter_cache: :image_count
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Categories
  has_many :image_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :image_categories
end
```

You'll need to add `image_count` field to your `categories` table and `category_count` in `images` table.

Once you are done adding the counters and fields, you'd need to reset the counters so that the fields are updated with the correct count values for the records already present in your db.

```
Category.find_each { |category| Category.reset_counters(category.id, :images) }

Image.find_each { |image| Image.reset_counters(image.id, :categories) }
```

Comment: thanks, any thoughts on how to implement? as said in question, not yet been successful with implementation

Comment: Note that you may need to use `reset_counters` to initialize the count column to its correct value `http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/reset_counters`

Comment: yes db is already populated so i guess that will be needed, thanks

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyE i was just updating the answer with the very same thing.

Comment: @Alfie i set the columns as integers i guess ?

Comment: Yeah, since they store the count, `integer` should be just fine

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "image_categories_count" of relation "categories" does not exist..... i get his when running the Category.find_each statement

Comment: Please update the relations in the join table as : `belongs_to :image, counter_cache: :image_count`
`belongs_to :category, counter_cache: :category_count`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110736/discussion-between-richlewis-and-alfie).

Answer (score 2):

A couple important things to consider with `counter_cache`:

- Certain Rails methods can update the database while bypassing callbacks (for instance `update_column`, `update_all`, `increment`, `decrement`, `delete_all`, etc.) and can cause inconsistent values for a counter cache. Same applies to any database changes outside of Rails.
- Creating/deleting a child model always requires updating the parent. To ensure consistency of the counter cache Rails uses an additional DB transaction during this update. This usually isn't a problem but can cause database deadlocks if your child model is created/deleted frequently, or if the parent model is updated frequently. (http://building.wanelo.com/2014/06/20/counter-cache-a-story-of-counting.html)

These problems will be exacerbated since you're using a counter cache across a join table.

If you want to do an efficient dynamic count, that's always up to date, then you can use a custom `select` with a grouped join:

```
@categories = Category.select("categories.*, COUNT(DISTINCT images.id) AS images_count").joins(:images).group("categories.id")

<% @categories.find_each do |c| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to '#', data: { :filter => '.' + c.name.delete(' ') } do %>
      <%= c.name %> (<%= c.images_count # <- dynamic count column %>)
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

The cost of this grouped join should be very small provided your foreign keys are indexed, and I'd strongly consider taking this approach if you need `images_count` to always be consistent with the true value, or if images are frequently being created or destroyed. This approach may also be easier to maintain in the  long  run.

Comment: thank you, this does seem a lot easier to maintain and saves me pain when updating records.